# How to write symfony2 effective

Tags: git, symfony, bundle, composer-php, php-5.5

I wrote some Symfony2 bundles, and everything ok, but ... i don't like the way i did. First, create a new symfony project, and I generate bundle Company/Mybundle (all of those is under git version control). But, when I have finished with them (some bundle), i create new github repository - Company/MyBundle, and uploaded them to packagist.org. 
Another "greatest" idea, was create 2 different git repository - one for symfony2 project and one for bundle, and when write something in bundle git - must do composer update on symfony2, but i can't test locally, and this is a problem.

Common problem here, how to get fresh copy of bundles. Or, how to have one (main repository, Symfony project), with one sub git (bundle repository).

How you do that? And, what is the "best practice" for this ?

Edit: Now, my symfony bundles look like this

```
app
src
`- vendor
    `- bundle1 - **git repository1**
    `- bundle2 - **git repository2**
web
```

All it's fine, but i wanna whole project has a git repository, maybe this is strange (i can't imagine for now), but i also wanna version control of config, parameteres, etc too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is more related to GIT than Symfony.

I suggest you to checkout GIT Submodulese: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Yes, that's another option, but not solve my problem. Maybe i miss some little thing in my mind, but i wanna have 2 git repositories in some folder (basicly)

Comment: Git submodules can help you: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Mm, that look great, i will test them. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer. If GIT Submodules work for you accept my answer.

Comment: Yes, i not accepted because i tested them, and with my ten minute expirience, i have another question. Submodules look great, but can i use in specific folder? Because that is unuseless, i don't wanna MyBundle folder in base root directory :\ PP I work with SmartGit, you can help me and with git bash commands, it's not problem.

Comment: Ye, in SmartGit i just have to select git repo directory, and then select Submodules -> Add, and for now everything look fine.

Answer (score 0):

just leave your bundle in `src/`, if you need it in a another project include it via composer. if you `–prefer-source` you will have the full git rep in your vendor, and can simply commit/push if you make changes.

if you used the hook on github, packagist will automatically update, so next time you do composer update it will update to the latest version for you.

The next thing is to use git tags, so you dont break older versions of your bundle when you make major changes for your current project.

Comment: Yes, i allready do this stuff, but i can't imagine how to update them. In this case, my bundle is on git version in main symfony2 project (the project also in other git version) - and that's the problem. Maybe, best choise for now is to store only bundles in src folder in git, not whole symfony2 project. But this is uncomfortably for config options.

Comment: Also updated first question, please take a look, and many, many thanks for all answers :)

Comment: `git clone mySymfonyProject' myproject` then `cd myProject/src` and `git clone myBundle` 
you can "nest" git checkouts, but be aware the mySymfonyProject will not touch your bundle. but this should be what you are looking for.

composer does the same your project may has a vendor direcotry, in it can be multiple different other git repositories. to make it safe most people use vendor/ in .gitignore

Comment: Exactly, i allready do this, but i was afraid it's not actually needed, and not "performancy orientied", but for now is only option.